# Manipulate does not accept constant (i.e. just number) as upper limit for variable

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-cdf

In the code below, If I chenage (4/([Zeta]*[Omega])) to, say 20, nothing is plotted. Why?
If I remove the two sliders at the beginning, nothing is plotted

```
ClearAll[\[Zeta], \[Omega]]
{Slider[ Dynamic[\[Zeta]], {0.1, 1.4, 0.1}], Dynamic[\[Zeta]]}
{Slider[ Dynamic[\[Omega]], {1, 5, 0.1}], Dynamic[\[Omega]]}
tf[\[Omega]_, \[Zeta]_] := 
 TransferFunctionModel[\[Omega]^2/(s^2 + 
     2 \[Zeta] \[Omega] s + \[Omega]^2), s]
f[t_] = OutputResponse[tf[\[Omega], \[Zeta]], UnitStep[t], t];
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[t], {t, 0, (4/(\[Zeta]*\[Omega]))}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, (4/(\[Zeta]*\[Omega]))}, {0, 2}}], {{\[Zeta], 
   0.2}, 0.1, 1.4}, {{\[Omega], 1}, 0.5, 4}
 ]
```

Comment: I'd define `f[t_, \[Omega]_, \[Zeta]_]` and use it accordingly in `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tf[o_, z_] := TransferFunctionModel[o^2/(s^2 + 2 z o s + o^2), s]
f[t_, o_, z_] = OutputResponse[tf[o, z], UnitStep[t], t];
Manipulate[Plot[f[t, o, z], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
           {{z, 0.2}, 0.1, 1.4}, {{o, 1}, 0.5, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works. I even could make the upper limit on t variable. I am new to mathematica - as you can obviously see from the totally "unclean" code.